# Passing multiple objects to angularjs $resource.save()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest, resources

I have an Operation Contract on the server that looks like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/RegisterOrganization", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
void RegisterOrganization(Organization organization, User admin);
```

Now on the client-side i have the following resource:

```
var RegisterOrganization = $resource(baseUrlService.getBaseUrl() + 'REST/Organization.svc/RegisterOrganization');
```

My question is how can i pass two objects as parameters like this:

```
RegisterOrganization.save(organization,admin)
```

I get a 500 server error by doing it like this, any ideas how i can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about your server side call but the `save` method of `$resource` first accepts query string parameters which will be sent as query string like:

```
REST/Organization.svc/RegisterOrganization?organizationName=StackOverflow&site=
```

While the 2nd parameter will be sent as JSON. And your server side call accepts data as JSON. So consider this change:

```
var data = angular.extend({}, organization, admin);
RegisterOrganization.save(null, data);
```